# Latex - странное поведение символа "минус"

Tags: latex

Есть такой минимальный воспроизводимый пример:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
("-")
\end{document}
```

Если попытаться собрать pdf-ку, то выдаётся ошибка:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. ("-"
```

Преодолеть ошибку можно двумя способами. И оба способа - странные... Вот они:

1. Закомментировать строку \usepackage[english,russian]{babel} Документ отображается правильно.
2. Написать тело документа, окружтв символ минуса пробелами: (" - ") Ошибка уходит, но документ при этом отображается НЕправилно. Вот так:

   ( - ")

Я предполагаю, чтот загадочное поведение знака "минус" (это действительно знак "минус" - проверял!) объясняется тем, что он воспринимается как символ переноса. Но как бороться с этим делом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вина пакетов `babel` и `babel-russian`.  Они
определяют так назваемые *shorthands*:

> *A *shorthand* is a sequence of one or two characters that expands
> to arbitrary TEX code.  Shorthands can be used for different kinds of
> things, for example: (1) in some languages shorthands such as
> `"a` are defined to be able to hyphenate the word if the
> encoding is `OT1`; (2) in some languages shorthands such as
> `!` are used to insert the right amount of whitespace; (3)
> several kinds of discretionaries and breaks can be inserted easily with
> `"-`, `"=`, etc.  (…)*

Если вам действительно нужны именно простые двойные кавычки, можете
попробовать вот так:

```tex
\catcode`@ = 11
\bbl@deactivate{"}
("-")
```

Или можете использовать русские кавычки вот так:

```tex
("`-"')

("<-">)
```

Comment: Всё работает нормально. Спасибо!